# Flux through a tetrahedron

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Im solving a problem and have stumbled can not wrap my head around the solution I get.

The problem is formulated:

> Calculate the flux of $\vec{F}=(x,z,0)$ out from the tetrahedron $x+2y+3z=6$ in the first octant.

My solution is the following:

Parametrization:
$r(x,y)=(x,y,\frac{6-2y-x}{3})$ with $0\leq y\leq 3-\frac{x}{2}, 0\leq x\leq 6$, which implies $\vec{N}=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},1)$.

Then i just evaluate the double integral:

$$\int^{6}_{0}\int^{3-x/2}_{0}\vec{F}\cdot \vec{N}dydx=\int^{6}_{0}\int^{3-x/2}_{0}(x,\frac{6-2y-x}{3},0)\cdot(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},1)dydx=10.$$

I've tried recalculating several times over and can not get the correct answer of 6. Which step am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the exercise is asking for the **total** outward flux of $F$ through the boundary of the tetrahedron (which is a solid)
$$T=\{(x,y,z): x+2y+3z\leq 6, x\geq 0,y\geq 0,z\geq 0\}.$$
So you just computed the flux through a part of the boundary $\partial T$ that is
$$S_1=\{(x,y,z): x+2y+3z= 6, x\geq 0,y\geq 0,z\geq 0\}.$$
You should now compute the flux through the rest of $\partial T$:
$$\begin{align}
S_2=\{(x,y,z): x+2y+3z\leq 6, x=0,y\geq 0,z\geq 0\}, \vec{N}=(-1,0,0),\\
S_3=\{(x,y,z): x+2y+3z\leq 6, x\geq0,y=0,z\geq 0\}, \vec{N}=(0,-1,0),\\ 
S_4=\{(x,y,z): x+2y+3z\leq 6, x\geq 0,y\geq 0,z= 0\}, \vec{N}=(0,0,-1).
\end{align}$$
They give $0-4+0$ and after adding your $10$ we find $6$ as expected.

You may also apply the divergence theorem. Then the total flux is
$$\iint_{\partial T}\vec{F}\cdot \vec{N}dS=\iiint_T \text{div}(\vec{F})dxdydz=\iiint_T 1dxdydz=|T|=\frac{6\cdot 3\cdot 2}{6}=6.$$

Comment: Just so I understand it correctly, when calculating the rest of the bounds, do i need to change the bounds or is it just the N vector that needs changing?

Comment: @AronFredriksson You have to change the surface and normal vector. See my edit.